# To design a complex method, should I bring in a helper class? 

Tags: c#, design-patterns

normally when I want to create a complex method A, in order to break it up into smaller pieces, I would end up with a helper Class `ClassA`, and call it like this

```
  Public T MethodA()
      {
        ClassA myClass = new ClassA(some parameter);
        return myClass.Output();
      }

  Class ClassA
  {
      T fields...

      Public ClassA(some parameter)
         {
             Initialize(some parameter)
             DoA();
             DoB();
         }

      Public T Output()
         {
             DoC();
         }
      void DoA();
      void DoB();
      ...

  }
```

so in fact ClassA is just a wrap of a huge method. I feel it is kind of a waste to create an instance in order to achieve this. Should I make it static?

what's the best design pattern for it?

Comment: What are you actually wasting? @x2.: Suggesting to make something static in a "oop way to design" question is misleading.

Comment: A huge method is probably a sign that you should refactor into additional classes and methods.

Comment: Do you mean you miss global methods/functions ?

Comment: seriously ?? you need to go through OOP first then dive into design patterns

Comment: Lots of loooooops and global state

Comment: @Frederiek: That's a pretty arrogant comment.

Answer (score 2):

So first problem is you say "huge method".  That tells me you need to break it up into smaller methods, each with a specific purpose.  You can call that method which will call the smaller ones, but if you have a method which say

1. Calls the database
2. Modifies the records
3. Sorts them
4. Groups them into another structure

This should be different methods in the object, each with their own function. This makes it a lot easier to test and debug later when there is a mistake in the code.

The second is that you don't need to make an object for one method you can always make that method [static](http://www.dotnetperls.com/static-method) so you don't need to instantiate a new object just to call it.  It looks like you are putting your logic in the constructor which I would refactor.  If you are returning the output for it just make it so you can do:

```
var myObject = new MyObject();
var results = myObject.DoFunction();
```

You have no need to put the logic in the constructor and then call another method for the result.  The constructor should have the minimum amount of code to get the object going, and then let the calling methods choose when they want that object to execute the business logic.

Answer (score 0):

Well if it is qualifies for the **Single-Responsibility** of the "**S** OLID" principles, then it is fine.

Parameters passed in constructor are usually immutable properties/members of the class.

You may also make it static but that will cause **hard dependency** which is discouraged.

Alternative is to use functional programming pradigm which will define it as below (assuming A and B are types):

```
var func = (A a) => return new B();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a static method on an existing class or a static class.

```
public static void Output(param)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer actually lies in the label "object orientation". If you want to design something in an oop-way, you have to put the methods inside the class of the primary object the method operates on.

What you want to do is using a procedural approach in a purely object oriented language like `C#`. There multiple possible ways to do this:

- As already mentioned, you can create a "tool" class which contains methods that are not particularly linked to an object class. This tool class then provides one or more static methods. This would be the closest thing to how you would implement it in a procedural language.
- If your main concern is that the method is too huge to include it in the object class it should be linked to, firstly consider to break up the method in smaller parts, and then consider implementing it as an extension method to the object class (which can be defined outside of the class).
- Finally, if it actually makes sense to have an object, but you do not want to create a new instance every time you use it, you can use the singleton pattern to make the class have only one instance which is available through a static method.

There may be other sensible ways in doing what you want, depending on your specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I will not call **any** methods in the **constructor**. A good programming practice is constructor should not throw an exception.

Before creating a class I will ask myself a question. "Am I going to use the methods in some other places?" If the answer is yes, then I will create a class. If No, I prefer to keep it as an implementation detail and make those ***Private*** methods. Because that is an implementation detail of the class.

Answer (score 0):

> normally when I want to create a complex method A

Wait, I think you are approaching the problem from the wrong side. Normally, you want to implement some kind of *functionality*, not a complex method.

When you realize that, you can take the explicit or implicit specification of the functionality and break it down into methods/classes/components/services/whatever.

Now if you are refactoring something instead, moving the method to a different class may be the first step to help you, but then I would choose an approach similar to the one described by Kevin, splitting it up into multiple methods, or maybe classes, when you identify different responsibilities in the process.

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly fine to end up with a separate class, but I'd go a step further and ask "what concept does it represent"?

If you can find a good name for the class it's an indication that it was something buried in your design that really wanted to "get out". By giving it a name and a place in the design you can better talk about it, reason about it and maybe even find other uses for it. You've made things more explicit and more understandable, and that's *a good thing*. From there you might find out that the originating class really doesn't need to know about the *implementation details* of the new class, and only cares about its *interface*. Congratulations, you've found another *concept* in your design that can be used to isolate concerns, both conceptually and physically.

From a refactoring perspective, this process is what Michael Feathers calls *sprout class* in his book "Working Effectively with Legacy Code". It's used to separate logic into testable, independent and understandable chunks.